# Android TextView invalidate doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I'm in front of a small invalidation issue on Android.
After creating my view on the Activity creation, i'm receiving a Listener Callback ("onSomething" in the example below") to update a TextView, however I'm not able to make it work... Can you help ?

Activity onCreate :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    init_views();
}
```

My method initializing the views :

```
private static TextView myTxtView;
private void init_views(){
     myTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtid);
}
```

Listener and TextView update :

```
@Override
public void onSomething(JSONObject data) {
    try {
        ... // my code

        myTxtView.setText(distance); // this doesn't work :( :(
        myTxtView.postInvalidate(); // this doesn't work  :( :(

    } catch (Throwable t){ return; }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if `onSomething` is actually called? Does your textview need to be static? Are you sure that `distance` is not null?

Comment: Yep onSomething is called and the TextView isn't affected by being static or not... doesn't work in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setText` has to be invoked on the UI thread.

```
myTxtView.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      myTxtView.setText(distance);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cannot apply the text ... "distance" needs to be final. But I have to manipulate this variable in the "onSomething" callback.

Comment: can you mark distance as final ? `final String distance = ...;`

Comment: ok found it, marking it as final just before launching the Runnable. 
A lot of code... Is there any more cleaner code ?

Comment: depends on your code is structured, but it is definitely possible

Answer (score 0):

you have to update a textview in activity you must use runOnUiThread

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override 
          public void run() { 

                   myTxtView.setText(distance);

        });
```